# issues compiling assembly code with x86_64-linux-android-gcc

Tags: assembly, gcc, compilation

I am trying to compile some assembly code I extracted from GLIBC version 2.31. Filename is "bsd-_setjmp.S".  The reason I need it is due to some undefined references (for _setjmp, etc.) when cross-compiling some Fortran code with the cross-compiler I built.  I am using x86_64-linux-android-gcc. The assembly code is (please help with formatting code blocks, please):

```
#include <sysdep.h>
#define _ASM
#define _SETJMP_H

/* x86/bits/setjmp.h says "never include <bits/setjmp.h> directly */
/* so will change line below accordingly and the -I path accordingly */
/* #include <bits/setjmp.h> */
#include <setjmp.h>

ENTRY (_setjmp)
 xorl %esi, %esi
#ifdef PIC
 jmp HIDDEN_JUMPTARGET(__sigsetjmp)
#else
 jmp __sigsetjmp
#endif
END (_setjmp)
libc_hidden_def (_setjmp)
```

The compiler errors, using

```
x86_64-linux-android-gcc -c bsd-_setjmp.S
```

are:

```
bsd-_setjmp.S: Assembler messages:
bsd-_setjmp.S:10: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `('
bsd-_setjmp.S:10: Error: unrecognized symbol type ""
bsd-_setjmp.S:10: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `('
bsd-_setjmp.S:18: Error: no such instruction: `libc_hidden_def (_setjmp)'
```

Please let me know what I have wrong in the assembly code.

Comment: that should be "x86_64-linux-android-gcc -c bsd-_setjmp.S" for the compile command.

Comment: You can [edit] your question at any time to fix this sort of thing.

Comment: Great.  Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Apparently neither header you included defined an `ENTRY()` macro.  Or they defined it in terms of `libc_hidden_def` which is isn't itself defined?  That's not GAS syntax, it's a macro.  Linux kernel code uses it.  IDK how the define it.  It might be as simple as `.globl x; x:` to define the label and mark it exported.  (Or given the `hidden`, probably `.hidden x` so it's visible at static link time, but not exported from the ELF shared object)

Comment: Thanks so much Peter.  Very illuminating - I'll have to see if I can find a libc_hidden_def macro defined in glibc.  I will test out the other things you mention such as defining with .globl and see if I can progress here.